# Gradle: exclude specific directory from testRuntime classpath

Tags: gradle

One of the unit tests picks up a wrong resource file because there's another directory in the classpath where a file exists with the same name.
The unwelcome directory is part of 'rootProject.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath'. (there are many sub projects, with circular dependencies.  Some of which these unit tests depend on hence the reason for using dependency this way)

How do I exclude such directory from testRuntime class path?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that worked.

Add  'runtimeClasspath -= ' entry in the build script.

```
sourceSets {

    test {
        java {
        //...
    }

    resources {
        //...
    } 

    runtimeClasspath -= files("/dir/you/want/to/exclude")
}
```